# Attributes of virtual base class methods/members in C# Class Inheritance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, coded-ui-tests, vs-unit-testing-framework

I want to use the VS2010 Test Framework for some Coded UI tests. I have setup the following base test class:

```
[CodedUITest]
public abstract class TestObjectBase
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    public TestObjectBase()
    {
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        Database.ResetArchiveDatabase();
        Database.ResetSettingsDatabase();
        Database.ResetTransactionsDatabase();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

So the question I guess is the following: The `[CodedUITest]`, `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]` attributes do not have the `AttributeUsage=` and `Inherited` members.

Would any instance of a child class that inherits from `TestObjectBase` have those attributes propagated to itself (in the case of the `[CodedUITest]` and its members (in the case of `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]`)?

Comment: What's preventing you from just trying it?

Comment: Funny. That's what my co-worker said after i made the post. Well, I might. I also might leave this question lingering as it is a good question in my opinion.

Comment: @bleepzter, if you find the answer, you should answer this question yourself and not just “leave it lingering”.

Comment: It really depends on how the Test harness runs the code. Using reflection, you can see inherited attributes whether or not you specify them as AttributeUsage inherited or not.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for [the `AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx) is `true`, so I would assume the same applies if you don't use `AttributeUsageAttribute` at all. And my tests seem to concur with that.

But as payo correctly points out, `AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited` is more of an recommendation. That's because there are several ways to get attributes of some type (or its member):

1. Call `GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false)` on the type. This way, no attributes from the base type(s) are inherited, even if they specified `Inherited = true`.
2. Call `GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true)`. This is the only way that actually honors the value of `AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited`.
3. Walk through the inheritance hierarchy and call `GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false)` on each type. This way, you get all attributes from the base type(s), even if they specified `Inherited = false`.

Most tools will probably go with #2, because it's the most sensible option, but certainly not the only one.